# Draw animated wallpaper using OpenGL on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'd like to create a application for windows xp, 7 that renders an animated wallpaper.

I tried setting up an OpenGL context on the desktop window and drawing to it:

```
HWND progman  = FindWindow("ProgMan", NULL);
HWND shelldll = FindWindowEx(p, NULL, "SHELLDLL_DefView", NULL);
HWND listview = FindWindowEx(s, NULL, "SysListView32", NULL);

if(!listview) return 1;

HDC hDc = GetDC(listview);
HGLRC cont = createOpenGLContext(listview);

if (!cont) return 2;

wglMakeCurrent(cont,hDc);
glClearColor(.1,.2,.5,1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
SwapBuffers(cont);
```

It worked but icons got drawn over.
How do i draw under the icons?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing but i cant seem to find createOpenGLContext in any library. If the function is yours, could  you please share it so I can try and compile your code?